# How to get a WordPress database value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a live chat service for a Wordpress site. Several of the options, including Chatra below, require something like the following to map logged in users based on some unique clientId value. In most cases, it seems that the $user_pass variable is used from the Wordpress database.

My question is how am I meant to get the clientID value to be dynamically generated from the logged-in user rather than a static value like the code below?

```
<script>
window.ChatraSetup = {
    /* current user’s generated string */
    clientId: 'kZMvWhf8npAu3H6qd57w2Hv6nh6rnxvg'
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get that through `ajax` method, on `wp-ajax.php` where the `wordpress ajax functions` are exists..create custom one

Answer (score 0):

In your template add the following:

```
<?php  
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>

<script>
   window.ChatraSetup = {
       clientId: <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but that returns the ID number, which I don't think is very secure. I tried to replace "ID" for "user_pass" but this makes the script fail to load.

Comment: You can do user_login or user_email not user_pass.

Comment: I just tried replacing with "user_email" but again the script fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I was missing a couple of "".

```
<?php  
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>

<script>
   window.ChatraSetup = {
       clientId: "<?php echo $current_user->user_pass; ?>"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wp_localize_script function.
Find a full article that explains how to do it here:
https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29796253)